# How do you obtain/split multiple string inputs in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a function which obtains multiple arguments from a person:

```
@bot.command(name='koth')
async def koth_announcer(*args):
```

But how am I able to split the arguments into strings at a certain point? For instance: The user will input this: `The Goblin Camp | -39,19 | 12:00 | 28/12`

I need to be able to split the string at `|`. I tried:

```
args = str(args).split('|')
```

But this still returns everything as separate. Like this:

```
["('The'", " 'Goblin'", " 'Camp'", " '|'", " '-39", "19'", " '|'", " '12:00'", " '|'", " '28/12')"]
```

Comment: ...but what is your expected output

Comment: I need something like `["('The Goblin Camp ', '-39,19')"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like so: first join the list then split it

```
@bot.command(name='koth')
async def koth_announcer(*args):
    msg = "".join(args) #joins the list of words first
    content = msg.split('|') #split the words at |
```

Comment: You can also write it as `content = "".join(args).split('|')`

Comment: Argh that worked perfectly thank you so much.

`['The Goblin Camp ', ' -39,19 ', ' 12:00 ', ' 28/12']`